# How to creat edit post button. Docpad

Tags: docpad

How to make the edit articles?

```
<a href="https://github.com/.../blob/master/src/documents/posts/<%=@document.name%>" target="_blank">edit</a>
```

But this does not work for file.html.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to change `@document.name` to the appropriate path within the repository the file is located. We can use `fullPath` instead of `name` for this, but we'll need to replace the `srcPath` that DocPad is configured with in order to get just the path relative to your project, rather than the absolute path on the file system.

```
<a href="https://github.com/.../blob/master/<%=@document.fullPath.replace(@srcPath,'')%>" target="_blank">edit</a>
```

Now, `@srcPath` is not actually available to us, so we'll need to make it so. We can define `srcPath` in our template data by adding the following to our [docpad configuration file](http://docpad.org/docs/config):

```
events:
    extendTemplateData: (opts) ->
        opts.templateData.srcPath = @docpad.getConfig().srcPath
```

Let me know if it works. If not, please post more about what you were expecting, and what results you got, and I'll happily help further.